# Draw a rectangle relative to the form size

Tags: c#, drawing, draw

I'm currently trying to draw a simple rectangle who's size and location is relative to the form size.
I think I have managed to get the width and height of the rectangle relative to the form size. However I cannot seem to get the x and y point to do the same.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;               
using System.Windows.Forms;        

public class DrawFill : Form       
{
    public DrawFill()
    {
        Size = new Size(500, 300);
        Text = "Draw and Fill";             
        BackColor = Color.White;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {       
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;                   
        Pen blue = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
        // Width is 100, Height is 50  
        g.DrawRectangle(blue, 10,20,  (Width - 100)/3, (Height - 50)/3));    
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 150, 20, (Width - 100) / 3, (Height - 50) / 3);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new DrawFill());      
    }
}
```

Every time I enlarge the form the two rectangle overlaps each other, which make me think that the x,y are not changing according to the screen size. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Use the ClientSize property instead.  Call Invalidate() in your Resize event handler so it gets repainted with the new size.  And set the ResizeRedraw and DoubleBuffered properties to *true* in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is true that you don't invalidate the form as resize events happen. So that is the first thing you need to fix in the code example. That said, doing so won't address the original question. For that, read on...

The original question reads, in part:

> Every time I enlarge the form the two rectangle overlaps each other,
>   which make me think that the x,y are not changing according to the
>   screen size.

I don't see anything in your code example that alters the x and y at all, never mind according to changes in the size of the form. So it's not much of a surprise that they don't.

A couple of things to keep in mind when doing something like this, scaling some simple object within the frame according to the frame's size:

- You need to apply the same scaling to both the location and size of the object
- You need to make sure you scale any adjustments you make to those properties as well (such as the -100 and -50 that you apply to the width and height respectively)

In the code example you give, you violate both of these guidelines. The x and y locations are never adjusted, and you don't scale the -100 and -50 by changes to the Width and Height (so, for example, if the Form is adjusted below 100 pixels wide, the rectangles just disappear completely because they are empty or have negative width).

If you can define the size of the rectangles purely in terms of their proportional size to the form, then all of the logic can go into the OnPaint() method. Otherwise, you will need to save values based on the initial layout of the form, so that you can preserve the proportions later.

Here is a version of the OnPaint() method body that might do what you want:

```
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;                   
    Pen blue = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);

    // Original form size is (500,300)
    // 
    // Rectangle Width is 100, Height is 50
    // 1st Rectangle is at (10,20), 2nd is at (150,20)
    // So proportionally, rect1 is (10/500, 20/300, 100/500, 50/300)
    //     = (0.02, 0.0667, 0.2, 0.1667)
    // and rect is (150/500, 20/300, 0.2, 0.1667) = (0.3, 0.0667, 0.2, 0.1667)
    //
    // note that the y, width, and height is the same for both rectangles

    float rectWidth = 0.2f * Width, rectHeight = 0.1667f * Height,
        x1 = 0.02f * Width, x2 = 0.3f * Width, y = 0.0667f * Height;

    g.DrawRectangle(blue, x1, y, rectWidth, rectHeight);
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x2, y, rectWidth, rectHeight);

    base.OnPaint(e);
```

Note that by defining the rectangle not in absolute terms, but rather in terms of their proportional size relative to the form, then it is easy to calculate the actual location and size based on the current size of the form.

You can use whatever proportion you want. Or you can define the exact size, but then in the constructor of your form, compute the proportions based on the exact size as compared to the initial form size.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation, gave me a good understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You did put in your code differents values for the X. It's 10 in the first line and 150 in the second. Would be it the problem?

But, to make sure that the values to the X will always be the same, why not to create a variable to them?

Like:

```
int x = 10; //Or whateverelse value you want
int y = 20;
int w = (Width - 100)/3;
int h = (Height - 50)/3;
g.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Blue, x, y, w, h);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x, y, w, h);
```

I did see you posted your code with sintax error as well at the '((Width'.

And a final tip. The Form width and height are bigger then the drawable area (a.k.a. ClientSize). The ClientSize is the size of the form excluding form's border, menus and status bar. Use this in your code.

I hope I did help.

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve is that if the form size change from (500,300) to something like (1000, 500) then the rectangle will change it's size and position relative to the form.